# Find the area of a rectangle using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have 8 points of a polygon that are given in image below:

[image]

**I want to find out the area of this shape using OpenCV Java**

Here is the current code I'm trying:

```
Mat temp_mat=new Mat();
List<MatOfPoint> temp_contour=new ArrayList();
temp_contour.add(new MatOfPoint(new Point(w1,w2),new Point(x1,x2),new Point(y1,y2),new Point(z1,z2)));
Imgproc.drawContours(temp_mat,temp_contour,0,new Scalar(255,0,0));
double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour.get(0));
```

But the `contourArea` value is returned as empty

I found some reference code for OpenCV Python, as follows:

```
import numpy
import cv2

contours = [numpy.array([[1,1],[10,50],[50,50]], dtype=numpy.int32) , numpy.array([[99,99],[99,60],[60,99]], dtype=numpy.int32)]

drawing = numpy.zeros([100, 100],numpy.uint8)
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('output',drawing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to convert it into Java. How would I go about finding the area of this shape?

Comment: where are the other 4 points?? your image has only 4 vertices......

Comment: I receive it as 4 Point objects

Point p1 = new Point(w1,w2)
Point p2 = new Point(x1,x2)
Point p3 = new Point(y1,y2)
Point p4 = new Point(z1,z2)

This is how it makes 4 corners & forms the polygon

Comment: You have only four points (defined by 8 numbers), not four points. Anyways; why are you just getting the first point with `.get(0)`? Why not `contourArea(temp_contour)`?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Those are actually Points returned by an opencv function which code I don't have access to, hence using these points I want to find the are of the shape

Reason i'm using .get(0) is as I already know in this case there is only only contour

Comment: @MohammedIrfan but you're using `.get(0)` on a variable that you have defined; an array of four points, so `.get(0)` will only return the first value of the array, which is a single point. Anyways you can calculate the area with mathematics quite easily.

Comment: as Alexander Reynolds says, try `double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);` and it might work.

Comment: What I was storing in temp_contour was one single object of List<MatOfPoint> and hence I was using .get(0) but if I pass contourArea(temp_contour), it throws List<MatOfPoint> cannot be applied to contourArea(Mat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the area of the polygon has nothing to do with OpenCV and can in fact be done without the library...

Assuming you have a polygon of 4 points `P1` until `P4`
[image]

then the area can be calculated as [image]

Comment: In your formula, what does x1y2 means? How shall I consider according to openCV,
Consider I have (X1,Y1)(X2,Y2) as (400.0,40.0)(300.0,250.0)
So what shall I consider X1Y2 in the above formula with these sample values?

Comment: x1 y2 is the multiplication of the x element of P1 by y element of p2...